# Most efficient way to compare two large text files in python?

Tags: python, windows, text, compare, bigdata

Hello everbody and sorry for my bad english,

I'm tryng to compare two large text files in python, their size is about 18 gb and they contain multiple combinations of different database values obtained with itertools.combinations, one combination for line.

file1 ex:

```
('1', '7')
('1', '3')
('1', '4')
```

file 2 ex:

```
('1', '4')
('1', '5')
('1', '7')
```

I need to:

1) print or to write on a text file the combinations which are not shared among these files.

2) not load the entire txt files in to RAM.

This is actually working:

```
with open('c:/python27/file1.txt', 'r') as f:
    while True:
        next_n_lines = list(itertools.islice(f, 1))
        if not next_n_lines:
            break
        with open('C:/python27/file2.txt', 'r') as f2:
            for line in next_n_lines:
                if not line in f2:
                    print line
```

This code is really the only thing that is working, i did it copying many other codes found here on stackoverflow, but is pretty slow (i calculated that it would be necessary more then one year to end the job and life is too short to wait this time).

If i try to use:

```
with open('c:/python27/file1.txt', 'r') as f:
    with open('C:/python27/file2.txt', 'r') as f2:
        for line in f:
            if not line in f2:
                print line
```

it just print the entire content of file1.

Do you have any suggestion to go faster or any other way to reach my goal?

Thanks

PS i'm not a coder, i never coded anything

Comment: You might want to look into hashing (and use sets for that task).

Comment: Have you considered a system call?  If you're on a UNIX system of any sort (including Linux), you have OS commands that will do this faster than Python could.

Comment: with a 64 bit version of python and some RAM, you could build a `set` of the lines of one of the files (you need 10-20GB+), and read the one sequentially to see if it's in it. That would cut down execution time a great deal. O(N**2) => O(N*log(N)) (roughly)

Comment: if the `line` isn't in `f2`, doesn't the read pointer go all the way to the end of the file, and thus mean all subsequent searches return False? if you move your second `with` statement inside the `for` loop, that might fix the issue.

Comment: @Uriel doesn't sets load file into RAM?

Comment: @Prune no, i didn't consider it, but now i'll install ubuntu and try

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre yeah i know, but for now i have to work with a 4gb toaster...

Comment: @Dontblameme: make sure you look up the commands you want before going to the trouble of installing a new OS.  :-)

Comment: @Dontblameme no, it means processing them into another data structure, then using this new information to give you the result. Note that `set`s have the xor (`^`) operator for (A u B) - (A n B) and if you have a lot of duplicate the memory consumption should be fairly low

Comment: @Hoopdady i'm trying this but seems pretty slow as the one i wrote, i suppose because the file2 is closed and opened for every operation so the speed of the disk becomes the bottle-neck.

Comment: if you have low memory, then create a first set with a part of the first file, read second file fully and note if it's not in part 1, proceed n times (n being the number of parts) and in the end, intersect the line to find the ones not being in any part

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre and Uriel ok i will try this, thank you